# Absolute href address resolves with prepended relative link?

Tags: html

I'm a bit baffled about this, so I'm guessing I must be overlooking something very simple or obvious.

I'm trying to provide some external links on a page advertising a bicycle, but the absolute links are resolving with the relative path prepended to it. Here is [the page] https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9972753/rambler.htm.

Click on any link and you'll see they resolve as:

location of HTML file(Dropbox)/"absolute link"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Rory

Comment: Please include the source directly in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the correct double quotes characters. You must use `"` instead of `”` otherwise your browser will add the correct double quotes itself and use the document base of the page (i.e. the dropbox link) as a prefix of whatever comes after the `href` attribute. In your case that includes the whole URL with the wrong doubles quotes, which the browser thinks are part of a relative URL (since the URL doesn't start with either an URL scheme (e.g. `http://`) or a forward slash.

[image]

PS: Is it possible that you've copy-pasted these links from Word or something?

Comment: Thanks, Val! You're right, the code was composed in Google Documents :/